# Building jq on Win10 using mingw fails at link time due to redefinition of pthread_key_create / pthread_setspecific / pthread_getspecific

Tags: windows, mingw

I apologize as I haven't dealt with C in a professional capacity in over 20 years, so maybe there's an obvious fix here.

When building within mingw64 I can get to the point where the linker is running for jq.exe, but the pthread specific code is giving me errors:

CCLD     jq.exe

(and this is just one of three similar errors that follow:)

**C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../lib\libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-thread.o):(.text+0x12e0): multiple definition of `pthread_key_create'; ./.libs/libjq.a(jv.o):C:\msys64\home\build\ws\jq\build\win64\tmp/../../../src/jv.c:338: first defined here**

I have used pacman to install what I believed were the necessary libraries/tools, but is there something that will prevent the configure/make process from including the pthread library since it looks like the preprocessor is trying to avoid including <pthread.h> ?  Is that even the correct approach for this problem?

My build steps:

- built the oniguruma library (v 5.9.6) and put that into jq/modules/oniguruma.
- autoreconf -fi
- ./configure
- make distclean
- scripts/crosscompile win64 --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-all-static --target=win64-x86_64 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-oniguruma=/home/build/proto/win64/usr/local

At the end of the compilation step, the linker fails because the WIN32 threading code from jv.c is colliding with the definitions in the winpthread files that are being linked in.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I can build jq 1.6 just fine in MSYS2 shell, but I didn't need `autoreconf` or `scripts/crosscompile` at all.

Here's what I did (I already had onigurama 6.9.8 on my system):

```sh
# change the next line to point to the proper destination
INSTALLPREFIX=C:/TEMP/jq
./configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX &&
 # fix building DLLs
 sed -i.bak -e "s/\(allow_undefined=\)yes/\1no/" libtool &&
 make install-strip &&
 echo SUCCESS
```

Comment: thanks - while i was able to build using msys2 as well, it required shipping additional DLLs (msys-2.0.dll) so we were looking to not use that particular compiler.  Though it is interesting that the link issues didn't exist there - i'm tabling this project for the time being but I will examine from that angle if i get back to it by comparing the make artifacts.

Comment: @flownover What you say (dependency on `msys-2.0.dll`) indicates you built not only in MSYS2 but also *for* the MSYS2 (which is a lot like cygwin, both of which I don't really consider to be native Windows). Instead you should really build for MinGW-w64 with one of the MinGW-w64 compilers that are also available in MSYS2 (via `pacman`), or with a separate MinGW-w64 compiler site (in my case https://winlibs.com/).